# How to route a sub-domain to a certain page using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I want to redirect a sub-domain to a certain url using rails
example: login.localhost:3000 to localhost:3000/login

Comment: I wouldn't use Rails for this.  I would do a redirect at the server level.

Comment: @ruby_newbie I don't get it. what do you mean by server level

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in routes.rb to handle the redirect on the rails level:

```
constraints subdomain: "login" do   
  get "/login" => redirect { |params| "http://www.myurl.com" }
end
```

What I was referring to about the server redirects would be setting up a 301 permanent redirect but don't worry you can do it at the rails level too.

for more info on subdomains please watch the following rails casts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains

Let me know if those steps don't work for you and I will try to assist.

Comment: would this redirect home.localhost:3000 to my index view? it doesn't work with me.
    constraints subdomain: "home" do
    get "/" => redirect {"home#index" }
    end